# In HTML5 drag&drop only dragstart fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I use only HTML5 drag&drop. I did it already by JQuery UI using but now need to do it by clear HTML5 API.

Like I just said: only dragstart fires. The rest of the events I don't catch. In dragstart function all seems to work correct: event.dataTransfer gets data, I checked it.
Here is the code:

```
$('#widget')
    .attr('draggable', 'true')
    .on('dragstart', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', $(this).attr('id'))
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(event.target, 24, 32);
        console.log('Im draggable');
        console.log(event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
    })
    .on('dragend', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /*$(this).css('top', event.pageX + "px");
        event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');*/
        console.log('dragend');
    });

$('#widget_dest')
    .click(function(event) {
        console.log("click widget_dest");
    })
    .on('dragenter', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("dragenter");
    })
    .on('dragover', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("dragover");
    })
    .on('drop', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        console.log("drop");

        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
        $(this).append($('#' + data));
        $('#' + data).css('top', event.pageX + 'px');
    });
});
```

The only logs I get are: dragstart (correct data) and of the click function.

I purposely inserted click finction to check Widget_dest's properties correctness. Click event fires, the rest of events not.

I'll be very thankful for any help
Victor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using `event.preventDefault()` in `dragstart`. This example works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/noziar/Q3eh3/4/

Also, even if I removed `event.preventDefault()` in most places, note that in `dragover` it is necessary, otherwise `drop` may not fire (at least in Chrome).

As a sidenote, I'm not sure how you're able to read/set properties on `event.dataTransfer`, since the jQuery event does not have the `dataTransfer` property - you can use `originalEvent` for that.

Here is my code:

- HTML:

  ```
  <div id="widget">I'm a widget</div>
  <div id="widget_dest">
      <span id="widget_box_title">Drag widgets into this box</span>
  </div>
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
  #widget_dest {
      position:absolute;
      top: 40px;
      border-style:solid;
      border-width:1px;
  }
  #widget {
      color:green;
  }
  #widget_box_title {
      color:red;
  }
  ```
- JS:

  ```
  $('#widget')
      .attr('draggable', 'true')
      .on('dragstart', function(event) {
          var original = event.originalEvent;
          original.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
          original.dataTransfer.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'))
          original.dataTransfer.setDragImage(event.target, 24, 32);
          console.log('Im draggable');
          console.log(original.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
      })
      .on('dragend', function(event) {
          $(this).css('top', event.pageX + "px");
          event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
          console.log('dragend');
      });

  $('#widget_dest')
      .click(function(event) {
          console.log("click widget_dest");
      })
      .on('dragenter', function(event) {
          console.log("dragenter");
      })
      .on('dragover', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("dragover");
      })
      .on('drop', function(event) {
          console.log("drop");
          var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
          $(this).append($('#' + data));
      });
  ```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I wasn't need to add event.preventDefault in deed.
But why doesn't it work on touch devices? How to fix it? Dragstart event.originalEvent is mouseevent, I need to change it to touchevent?